# Hadoop Map Reduce Program to make Service Call

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I Would like to make Service call for each row of File . Our Source File is greater than 50 GB. Iterating over 50GB of Row might take more time. Is there any built-in feature or any Map Reduce program need to be written to make call to service for each row. Since Map Reduce offer little bit of parallelization. Is there any custom tool already build this requirement

Answer (score 1):

The basic requirement for map-reduce, is tasks should be run in parallel without any impact on individual results. if your service call is independent of other stuff, you can use map reduce. I think only map will suffice, to take care of reading each row and doing a service call. However, you need to think the other side of the map too. What are you going to do with the service call and eventually with map. That part decides the reducer thing

Comment: Thanks Ramzy, we will be Making call to service and get value. we need to update row with service call value, i.e. we can think of as adding another column either same file or different hdfs file, for this we can perform insert into another hive internal table. based on reading of row.

Comment: ok good, accept the if you are satisfied, or you can wait for more answers